# Certbot or Let’s Encrypt add excess ".com" to domain

Tags: nginx, web, server, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have server with multiple domains. And certbot works fine for all of them, excepts one.
Let's use "blog.domain.staging.com" as example for this question.

```
certbot certonly -t -n --dry-run --agree-tos --renew-by-default --email "${LE_EMAIL}" --webroot -w /usr/share/nginx/html -d blog.domain.staging.com
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for blog.domain.staging.com
Using the webroot path /usr/share/nginx/html for all unmatched domains.
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. blog.domain.staging.com (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Fetching https://blog.domain.staging.com.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/YWnMAB2mDZFl4-tEO1BCrKc3vP6yeAL2JVZP-A-BRV4: Error getting validation data

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: blog.domain.staging.com
   Type:   connection
   Detail: Fetching
   https://blog.domain.staging.com.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/YWnMAB2mDZFl4-tEO1BCrKc3vP6yeAL2JVZP-A-BRV4:
   Error getting validation data

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
   your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
   firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
   client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
   that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
```

You can see that hostname has additional ".com" and I don't know why and how to fix that.

Comment: can you show your config i.e: `sudo nginx -T`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo in the nginx config. Redirect link from http to https was with additional ".com". That was the problem.